# Java concurrent hashmap missing values

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, concurrenthashmap

I'm using Java's Concurrent Executors to read in several files at once and write the info to a hashmap. The files are for daily logs that look something like this:

```
+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+
| Member ID | Time  | Weight    | Fat % |
+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+
| 1123141   | 1:03  | 162       | 21.2  |
| 5321430   | 1:10  | 131       | 25.3  |
| ...       | ...   | ...       | ...   |
+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+
```

And the hashmap has Member names as keys, and for the values I've created a class "MemberProperties" that has lists for the time and other properties. I'm trying to use multiple threads to read in multiple days at once, write the data to the hashmap, and then do data analysis on a per-member basis. Here's how the code looks

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.IOException;

class MemberProps {
    ArrayList<Date>    time;
    ArrayList<Integer> weight;
    ArrayList<Float>   fat;

    public MemberProps() {
        this.time   = new ArrayList<>();
        this.weight = new ArrayList<>();
        this.fat    = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

public class MemberFileReader {

    public ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, MemberProps> MemberHash;
    public ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    public void readFiles() {

            //Get this week's files 
            File folder = new File("C:\\User\\Temp");
            File[] files = folder.listFiles();

            for (File fl : files) {
                executor.execute(new FileReader(fl.toString()));
            }
            executor.shutdown();
    }

    private final class FileReader implements Runnable {

        private String filepath;

        public FileReader(String filepath) {
            this.filepath = filepath;
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {

            try {
                String line = null;
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    MemberProps member = new MemberProps();

                    String[] split_line = line.split("\\t");
                    int member_id = Integer.parseInt(split_line[0]);
                    member.time.add(Date.parse(split_line[1]));
                    member.weight.add(Integer.parseInt(split_line[2]));
                    member.fat.add(Float.parseFloat(split_line[3]));

                    // If not absent, will return member's values
                    member = MemberHash.putIfAbsent(member_id, member);

                    if (member != null){ 
                        member.time.add(Date.parse(split_line[1]));
                        member.weight.add(Integer.parseInt(split_line[2]));
                        member.fat.add(Float.parseFloat(split_line[3]));
                        MemberHash.put(member_id, member);
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException E){
                // caught exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that for some reason, values come up missing in the lists. For example, for a member with 10 logs, I might have 10 times but only 9 weights/fats, or similar 9 times but 10 weights, etc. From debugging, it seems like the issue might happen when different threads try to `get` the same member and `put` at the same time, but I'm not sure. Any ideas? To fix this I'm thinking about having different hashmaps for each thread, and then joining the maps after, but idk if there's a simpler solution.

Comment: The `synchronized` keyword on your `run()` method will have no effect because each task you submit to the executor service is a distinct instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks for these good suggestions, am updating my code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList.add is not thread safe. You should synchronize adding to those lists in MemberProps e.g.

```
class MemberProps {
    private ArrayList<Date>    time;
    private ArrayList<Integer> weight;
    private ArrayList<Float>   fat;

    public MemberProps() {
        this.time   = new ArrayList<>();
        this.weight = new ArrayList<>();
        this.fat    = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public synchronized add(Date d, Integer w, Float f) {
        this.time.add(d);
        this.weight.add(d);
        this.fat.add(f);
    }
}
```

Then use those synchronized methods like this:

```
if (member != null)) {
    Date d = Date.parse(split_line[1]);
    Integer w = Integer.parseInt(split_line[2]);
    Float f = Float.parseFloat(split_line[3]);
    member.add(d, w, f);
}
```

Note that you should not put the member into the map a second time since it is already there, you just need to add to the existing instance.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this seems to be fixing the issue. So I read on the Javadoc for array list that "the list should be 'wrapped' using the Collections.synchronizedList method... `List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));`". Would you  happen to know what's the difference between having the lists be synchronized vs the add method?

Comment: No Collections.synchronizedList would not solve the problem here as you need to synchronize the add to all three lists at the same time Collections.synchronizedList only makes a single list thread safe.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that you need to synchronize read access to the lists as well.

Comment: @AndyTurner isn't that taken care of kind of? If I'm just calling the add method, where else does the read need to be synchronized?

Comment: @sw_buddy "If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally." You have to use synchronized reads to ensure visibility of the writes; otherwise you don't have a happens-before relationship.

Comment: Ok, so then should I add, in the add method, `synchronized(this) { this.time.add(d)...}`?

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding to the `ArrayList`s safely. You need to externally synchronize structural modifications, as stated [in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Specifically, your approach of "put if absent, then put again if there was already something there" doesn't work because multiple threads can be executing that code at the same time.

Use `compute`:

```
MemberHash.compute(member_id, (k, member) -> {
  if (member == null) {
    member = new MemberProps();
  }
  // Add things to member.
  return member;
});
```

`compute` executes atomically, so you won't get two threads trying to add at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I see from the Javadoc why this is an issue. I tried implementing your idea but I'm getting an issue with this, where you put `//Add things to member.` I wrote `member.weight.add(Integer.parseInteger(...))`, and it's saying "local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final", is this not what you meant?

Comment: Which variable is it complaining about?

Comment: It complains about the lines where I add to the lists, so I think "member" in particular is the local variable, and calling the add method is causing the issue?